# Automatically capture acronyms

Tags: acronyms

I'm writing my thesis using Latex. And I'm wondering if there is an automatic or an easy way to write my acronyms. I did that before in Microsoft Word where I search for all words that are upper case then add them to my acronyms and sort them alphabetically?

Comment: @Rmano I don't see how this is a similar question.

Comment: @Rmano: That's a completely different problem. The OP is after automation, not for the basic usage of acronyms

Comment: You could use grep to search for all uppercase characters and generate the TeX commands.

Comment: Just to add to the question: **and sort them alphabetically**

Comment: @latexfan Done :)

Comment: What about packages `glossaries` or `acro`?

Comment: My guess is that the answer is no. This said, it is easy to do this from the command line using tools like sed. For example,  `sed  -i .bak "s@[[:<:]][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*[[:>:]]@\\\ac{&}@g" file.tex` does what you want on my system.  This will replace any "word" in the file `file.tex` that  consists of 2 or more capital letters with `\ac{<word>}`. The original file is saved as `file.tex.bak` just to be safe.

Comment: @Andrew How about U.S. and cdROM? Not easy to use regex to identify acronyms and abbreviatons, although you can probably catch about95%.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides The question says, well suggests, that they are all upper case. Allowing `.`s in the regular expression would be easy enough, but I agree it's unlikely to be complete accurate. As for cdROM, surely it would be CD or CDROM:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function FindAcronyms ( file )
    local param
    local Table = {}

    local f = assert(io.open(file, "r"))
    local t = f:read("*all")
    f:close()
    for param in t:gmatch ("[^%l]%s?(%u+)%p?%s")
    do
    table.insert(Table, param)
    end

    table.sort(Table)
    tex.print("\\bigskip")
    for i,acronym in ipairs (Table)
        do
        tex.print (i.." : "..acronym.."\\\\")
        end
end

\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\FindAcronyms}{%
    \directlua{FindAcronyms("\jobname.tex")}
}


\begin{document}

CCC! SomeThing ELSe AAA, CABA enD BAA 


\FindAcronyms


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `\jobname.tex`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are after, but may be package [acronym](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) will be of interest to you. It expands acronyms on first use and allows you to compile a list of them all.

Comment: I know this. But this is not what I'm looking for in my question.