# Automatically detect acronyms without \ac or \gls around them

Tags: pdftex, acronyms, automation

#### My Situation:

I am using `glossaries` package to manage my acronyms.
They are all neatly defined in one file with a list generated automatically.
But I have to confess: I was very inconsistent in using `\gls{}` inside the main document.

- Now, I ended up with a structured `acronyms.tex`:

```
\newacronym{rx}{RX}{receive}
[...]
```

- But a chaotic `main.tex` (example made up):

```latex
The \gls{rx} channel is the receiving channel, 
but only if Rx-buffer has RX capacity. 
Also receive channels have \emph{rx}-flags [...]
```

- That is, acronyms may be either correctly escaped, the acronym in any caps or written out. I want all to be correctly escaped.
- Additionally, the acronyms may occur inside other words. Those should stay the same.

#### Question:

Is there a quick solution to clean up the messed up `main.tex`?

Preferably automatically, using the strucutred data in `acronyms.tex` and with plain pdflatex / latexmk.

#### Some Ideas:

I got pretty far using find/replace with regex, but it is very tedious and often missing edge cases.

Fully automating the process seems hard, see: [Typesetting acronyms without explicitly marking them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549914/typesetting-acronyms-without-explicitly-marking-them).
But detection of non-`\gls{}` entries with not too many false positives would already do the job for me.

Skimming `acro` and `glossaries` manuals, I only find ways to automate the list of abbreviations and the index (700 pages, I could very well have missed something).

There is a very [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242078/automatically-capture-acronyms) answer. Also others that [use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248632/highlight-every-occurrence-of-a-list-of-words) [LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165218/macro-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-word) and [XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107014/automatically-apply-special-formatting-to-selected-words-in-text). So probably it is possible to hack something together in lua/regex. Unfortunately, I only know Python...

So before I reinvent the wheel, I would like to know if anyone already faced this problem.

Comment: pdftex has essentially no access to the text, so if using pdftex a regex edit to fix your source is the only practical option. If using luatex you could use the  input buffer callback to do lua string replace on the fly, but I think fixing the source would be preferable

Comment: Imho searching and replacing in the source in a semi-automatically way (with regex) is the only sensible way.

Comment: yes, I fixing the source is much preferred, because maybe others need to build the project in the future. I am not sure about switching engines atm. So other way would be better. 
@UlrikeFischer I do so, but I tend to miss many edge cases, like start of line, hyphens, colons, \emph{} around the word. Maybe I try to write a Python script to aid in that.

Comment: well I would use some grep to get a list of "rx/RX/Rx" and go through it to handle the cases.